# Making improvements to a program which converts Json to XML and vice-versa in Java

Tags: java, json, xml

Need some help in refactoring a Java code, which takes one string as input either XML tag or JSON key-value pair and returns it's equivalent JSON or XML. Only simple String methods are used in the program. I want suggestions on how the code can be made smaller and generic. There are some cases where the code fails. E.g when attributes are added to the XML. Are there any modules or tricks that can be very helpful in these cases ?
The code is -

```
package converter;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = sc.nextLine(); // input string
        if (inputString.startsWith("<")) { // if string is xml
            if (inputString.contains("/>")) { // if xml is a self closing tag
                int startIndex = inputString.indexOf('<');
                int endIndex = inputString.indexOf("/>");
                String key = inputString.substring(startIndex+1,endIndex);
                System.out.println(createJSON(key));
            }
            else {
                String key = extractKeyFromXML(inputString);
                String value = extractValueFromXML(inputString);
                System.out.println(createJSON(key,value));
            }
        }
        else if (inputString.startsWith("{")) { // if string is JSON
            if(inputString.contains("null")) { // if JSON contains a null value
                String key = extractKeyFromJSON(inputString);
                System.out.println(createXML(key));
            }
            else {
                String key = extractKeyFromJSON(inputString);
                String value = extractValueFromJSON(inputString);
                System.out.println(createXML(key, value));
            }
        }
    }

    public static String extractKeyFromXML(String xmlStr) {
        int startIndex = xmlStr.indexOf('<');
        int endIndex = xmlStr.indexOf('>');
        return xmlStr.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex).trim();
    }

    public static String extractValueFromXML(String xmlStr) {
        int startIndex = xmlStr.indexOf('>');
        int endIndex = xmlStr.indexOf("</");
        return xmlStr.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex).trim();
    }

    public static String createJSON(String key, String value) {
        return "{\"" + key + "\":\"" + value + "\"}";
    }

    public static String createJSON(String key) {
        return "{\"" + key + "\" : null }";
    }

    public static String extractKeyFromJSON(String jsonStr) {
        int startIndex = jsonStr.indexOf('{');
        int endIndex = jsonStr.indexOf(':');
        return jsonStr.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex).replaceAll("\"", "").strip();
    }

    public static String extractValueFromJSON(String jsonStr) {
        int startIndex = jsonStr.indexOf(':');
        int endIndex = jsonStr.indexOf("}");
        return jsonStr.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex).replaceAll("\"", "").strip();
    }

    public static String createXML(String key, String value) {
        return "<" + key + ">" + value + "</" + key + ">";
    }

    public static String createXML(String key) {
        return "<" + key + "/>";
    }

}
```

Comment: refactoring, migrate the q to code review.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks @AdiPrasetyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point making it smaller or more generic until you've got rid of the bugs. It's full of assumptions about the input, for example that XML elements will end on the same line where they begin, or that there will only be one element per line, or that the value will not contain special characters like `"` or `&lt;`.

Don't try to parse XML "by hand" in this way, always use a real XML parser. StackOverflow is riddled with questions of the form "How can I generate XML like {insert oddball rule here} because the receiving application will only accept it in that form." Don't become part of that problem.